# How to make Windows console cursor jump to next line at the end of the line

Tags: c, windows, console

I am having problems with a terminal emulator I am working on, and I have managed to narrow down the problem to a weird cursor behavior in the Windows console.
In a regular cmd, when you write character exactly to the end of the line, the cursor jumps to the next line. (See below picture)
[image: cmd cursor behavior]

When I try to achieve the same with printf in a program I write, the cursor stays on the same character. (See below picture)
[image: cmd cursor behavior]

I have managed to achieve the "cmd-like" result by printing the hacky `" \b"`, but I am trying to find a better way to do that (i.e., the first character at the next line might be meaningful, and I don't want to erase it. Reading that character would of course not be elegant).

I am looking for a way to make that happen automatically. Some configuration of the console maybe?
Does anybody here have any idea how to do that?

A code example (assuming the console has a default size of 80):

```
int main() {
    printf("12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890");
    fflush(stdout);
    getc();
    return 0;
}
```

If you run this code, after the print, the cursor will stay on the character 0 at the end of the line. 
My question is how to make the cursor appear on the beginning of the next line, without changing the hard coded string.

Comment: You haven't included the picture

Comment: Both pictures are inside the post

Comment: Do you create a console buffer for that? Or is it a separate program from cmd?

Comment: Just a simple console application in visual studio

Comment: Please, you don't include any code, and the question is not about programming at all (just on how the windows console application works)  Please, edit the question to reflect what you are doing, the expected response and the actual received response.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details.

Comment: I added a code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode

The flag DISABLE_NEWLINE_AUTO_RETURN seems to be enabled by default in VS.

Answer (score 0):

In windows the end of line is represented as "\r\n" not (as in unix) "\n". The \r is a carriage return and the \n is a newline. So emitting "\r\n" for a newline should solve your problem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: The data is not static of course, it is coming from another application. I just want the cursor to always be after the current character. To output newline, I would have to count characters and write it at the end of the line, which is even worse than just adding " \b" after every printf.

Comment: Many windows libraries automatically insert the `\r` before a `\n` if you mark the `FILE *` pointer as text, just to ensure portability with UNIX environments.  Your recommendation is useless anyway, as the question is not about C programming as tagged.  We have seen no code at all.